# Using mysql now() in a php calculation

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that holds id, name, email, and date. The date field was populated using now().

I can output these records to screen using PHP. No problems there.  However, I want an extra column that shows how long a person has been registered.  How do I subtract a date column in mysql entered as now() from right now.

This is what I have so far but it is not working for me:

```
$date = $row['date'];
$now = new DateTime();
echo $date->diff($now)->format("%d days, %h hours and %i minuts");
```

So I would end up with something like:

id.....name..............email................date reg........length reg
1......michael clarke....mclarke@gmail.com....11/02/2016......2 days 5h 2mins

Thanks,  Andy ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$row['date']` is a string, not a `DateTime` object so you can't call `diff` on a non object. Fix that and your code is good

```
$date=DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", "2015-12-01 12:56:32");
$now = new DateTime();
echo $date->diff($now)->format("%d days, %h hours and %i minutes");
```

I have used `Y-m-d H:i:s` because that is the format used by `NOW()` so your date time must be stored as that. However if your field is only of type `DATE` and not `DATETIME` you can simply change the format identifier  to `"Y-m-d"`

**Output**

```
10 days, 3 hours and 1 minutes
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/517149)**

Comment: Hanky, that works for that specific date/time, 2015-12-01 12:56:32, but the dates in the mysql table change depending on when someone registers.  How can those values be pulled and get them to take the place of 2015-12-01 12:56:32 which is hard coded?

Comment: Obviously put your variable name back there. `DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $row['date']);`

Comment: Yip, that's what I had done. Still getting errors, so I assumed I had it wrong. Thanks, Hanky I will work on it later, I must not be seeing the obvious.

Comment: I think the only possible issue is format. What format is your data stored in exactly? is it a date or a datetime field?